# give big-O estimate for f (n) = 3n log(n!) + (n 2 + 3) log n

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

> Give a big-O estimate for f (n) = 3n log(n!) + (n^2 + 3) log n, where
>   n is a positive integer.
>
> Solution:         First, the product 3n log(n!) will
>   be estimated. From Example 6 we know that log(n!) is O(n log n). Using
>   this estimate and the fact that 3n is O(n), Theorem 3 gives the
>   estimate that 3n log(n!) is O(n^2 log n).
>
> **Next, the product (n^2 + 3)
>   log n will be estimated. Because (n^2 + 3) < 2n^2 when n > 2, it
>   follows that n^2 + 3 is O(n^2 ). Thus, from Theorem 3 it follows that
>   (n^2 + 3) log n is O(n^2 log n). Using Theorem 2 to combine the two
>   big-O estimates for the products show**s th**at f (n) = 3n log(n!) + (n^2
>   + 3) log n is O(n^2 log n).**

the Text in Bold is what i didnt get, i know that (n^2 +3) is O(n^2), but iant log n is O(n), and with combination rules (f1 f2)(x) = O(g1(x)g2(x))

which means O(n^2) * O(n) = O(n^3), but the text-book keeps saying its O(n^2 log n).!!

I am missing something but what is it ?

the example from the text-book " discrete mathematics and its applications 7th edition " Page 214

Comment: Logarithms grow much slower than polynomials. In other words, $n$ grows much faster than $\log n$, hence the asymptotic behaviours $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ and $\mathcal{O}(n)$ are different.

Comment: i know but log takes O(n) in worst case

Comment: sorry*, log n takes O(n)

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're saying. $\log n$ is in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ and $n$ is in $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: what is the big-O of f(n) = log n ? its O(n) , right ?

Comment: I don't really understand why you keep asking that question (I'm not trying to be rude). No, as I've stated, if $f(n) = \log n$ then $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ is $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58321/discussion-between-mohamed-kira-and-eff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It often happens that an algorithm has $\mathcal O(\log n)$ average-case and $\mathcal O(n)$ worst-case performance. (One example is searching for an element in a binary tree: this is usually $\mathcal O(\log n)$, but becomes $\mathcal O(n)$ when the tree is very unbalanced.)

You may have been confused by this to think that $\log n$ is somehow "inherently worst-case linear", but that's not true. There are plenty of algorithms where this *doesn't* happen.

Moreover, saying that "$\log n$ takes $\mathcal O(n)$ in the worst case" is a type error, in a sense. The function $f(n) = \log n$ is not an algorithm, and doesn't have a worst case: it is always only one value.  We can say that $\log n = \mathcal O(n)$ in the same way that $\log n = \mathcal O(n^2)$ or $\log n = \mathcal O(2^n)$: $\mathcal O$-notation is always just an upper bound. But $\mathcal O(\log n)$ is more precise: not all functions in $\mathcal O(n)$ are also in $\mathcal O(\log n)$.

A function like $n^2 \log n$ grows faster than $n^2$ but slower than $n^{2.0000001}$; this is how you should think of log factors in $\mathcal O$-notation. You should keep $\mathcal O(n^2 \log n)$ as $\mathcal O(n^2 \log n)$: replacing the log by any polynomial would give a weaker estimate.